# what includes the cPanel website backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backups, channel

I own a web app and I need to download the latest backup of it. I don't need the media like images, audios (lots of it), videos, etc. I only need the code, and specifically, only the code that was built by us, don't need the server config files and  other low-level stuff.

As you know I have several options: Full Backup, /home directory backup, Database backup, etc.
The problem is that if I do a full Backup I might download 30GB and, as I mentioned I don't need all the heavy media files. And I don't know if /home directory will do the same as the media is stored in it.

And regarding the database backup, I am using a CMS so those media files are referenced inside the databases. The question is: is it only a reference or it's the actual media file stored inside the database?

It may sound dumb, but hey, we are not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Every system I know that stores large numbers of big files(Media) stores them externally to the database. So you will have reference of actual media file.

Also, if you're going to have thousands of media files, don't store them all in one giant directory - that's a performance bottleneck on some file systems.

Instead,break them up into multiple balanced sub-trees.